# 32Feet.net Compatibility with Xamarin Android Watch

Tags: xamarin.android, bluetooth-lowenergy, 32feet

When I install 32feet to Xamarian for Android, the follow errors occur:

Error   NU1202  Package 32feet.NET 3.5.0 is not compatible with monoandroid12.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0). Package 32feet.NET 3.5.0 supports:

- net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
- net-cf (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0,Profile=CompactFramework)

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The package InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth is the current version and supports Android. So don't use 32Feet.net package anymore. Use package InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth instead.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question?

Comment: Yes. 32feet no longer fits Xamarian for Android,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).